# Laravel: what is the best practice for injecting into multiple pages a subview which has javascript

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a social networking application.

In various pages such as the "profile", "dashboard" and "trending" pages I wish to display multiple posts.

I have made a `post.blade.php` file in my `resources/views/includes` folder.

I have included this file in all pages that require it like so:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    @include('includes.post', ['post' => $post])
@endforeach




@section('myJavascriptCode')
<script>
    // I want to paste in the Javascript code necessary for "includes.post" here
</script>
@endsection
```

My guess is that I should write a corresponding `post.js` file and include this script in each of my pages that displays posts. However this would be tedious to maintain parallelism between my blade template files and their corresponding js files.

`<script src="post.js"></script>`

If this is the case,in which directory should I store my js? I would imagine in a `resources/js/includes` directory which mimics the path where my `post.blade.php` file is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Store your js file in your laravel public folder and call it this way to use

```
<script src="{{asset('post.js')}}"></script>
```

this work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

check this link : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#stacks

you can use @stack and @push to import script to parent from child.